# Android In-App Purchase of consumable

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, billing

I've implemented Google's Billing Services API in my current app. I have several items that are consumables due to their nature. For example, if the user buys consumable AA, the costumer gets 20 coins. I'm currently storing that value of 20 coins on the user's device. Is there a way to store this value in Google's servers? The reason I'd like to do this is because if someone roots their device, they can make the purchases, then make a copy of the file that stores the consumable content and keep restoring the file as they use the consumables in the app. I have encrypted the data stored in the file making it difficult to make changes to it, but you can make a back up and restore as they wish.
If you have other suggestions, please let me know.

Thank you,
A

Answer (score 0):

If it is a managed item, then purchase history is stored by google, and you can make queries to their API to find out how much currency the user has purchases. However, you will need to track expenditure separately on your own servers, as otherwise whenever you query the purchases, you'll end up crediting the user with that amount, regardless of how much they've acquired.

In short, Google does not provide a nicely tailored system for this. For security, you're better off storing details on your own server, or encrypting them on the device as you noted.

Comment: I'd like to store the data on a server and have a back up on the device in case the device does not have Internet connection at that moment and also to allow the user to utilize their purchases on other devices.
I was looking into Google Cloud Save service. Has anyone ever used this to save small amount of data per user? Are there any tutorials out there that shows you how to implement this service? I haven't found one yet.